# IBM Power 750 Express SCAN_ERROR_CHRP message

Tags: hardware, ibm

I'm seeing the following error on my IBM Power 750 Express (8233-E8B) server.

From `errlog`, I see:

> Sep 15  sysplanar0 P PLAT_DUMP_COMPLETE
>   Sep 15  errdemon   T ERRLOG_ON
>   Sep 15  sysplanar0 P SCAN_ERROR_CHRP
>   Sep 15  sysplanar0 I PLAT_DUMP_INDICATOR
>   Sep 15  sysplanar0 P SCAN_ERROR_CHRP

Those **SCAN_ERROR_CHRP** are as:

- P7  B170B838 The clocks are in the wrong state for this SCOM operation.
- P7  B1812A11 The TPMD (thermal/power management device) failed to communicate with a processor over the I2C bus.

So, my guess is some HW issue; in the CEC as per the SCAN_ERROR_CHRP.

Any clues for my scenario?